# Python Script to saves as Raster Img with new CRS, Map View Extent, and x,y Resolution

Tags: raster, pyqgis, layers, resolution

I am currently trying to write a python script that can do the same thing as when you right-click on a raster image and click save as. So I am still figuring out how to change the CRS for the raster image in python, choose the map view extent option and not the layer extent option, and change the layer resolution

[image: Save As Raster Img].

I've tried:

```
        new_cord = iface.mapCanvas().extent()

    crsSrc =  layer_find.crs() 
    crsDest =  QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(102671, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)  # WGS84 or UTM Zone

    renderer = layer_find.renderer()
    provider = layer_find.dataProvider()

    pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
    pipe.set(provider.clone())
    pipe.set(renderer.clone())

    file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(filename)
    file_writer.Mode(1)

    file_writer.writeRaster(pipe, provider.xSize(), provider.ySize(), new_cord, provider.crs())
```

But the file that is being written is around 7gb and just causing my QGIS to freeze.